# ConstraintLayout: Overlap ImageView on Toolbar and set image Height based on width by GuideLine

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-constraintlayout

### I want to achieve these points (first image):

- `Toolbar` height must be 35% of screen height
- The center of `ImageView` must be placed on the bottom of `Toolbar` (shown in image)
- Width of `ImageView` must be 33% of screen width
- The ratio of `ImageView` must be 1:1 (resize based on screen size)

[image]

### My code is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="io.inov.nepalwaterapp.UserProfileActivity">

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guidelineToolbarHeight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".35" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyApp.ActionBar"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guidelineToolbarHeight"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guidelineImageStart"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".33" />

        <android.support.constraint.Guideline
            android:id="@+id/guidelineImageEnd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".66" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/avatar_diver"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,1:1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guidelineImageStart"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guidelineImageEnd"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

### Result of above code is:

[image]

Please help me to find the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: I think currently it is not possible with constraint layout (I'm not sure though). When image size is wrap content then it is free you can move it anywhere. but when image is match parent you can't move it anywhere freely, it is bound with it's parent view.In your case Image is dynamic so it need a parent to create it's size.It will go either below toolbar or above toolbar to create aspect ratio 1:1. ImageView don't know what will be it's height. But when it is wrap content constraint layout know everything about imageview size so only WrapContent image will work in your case I think.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#019AE8"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".35"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".70" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="w,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".33"
        tools:src="@drawable/ic_user" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Explanation: your toolbar takes 35% of height and you are not able use negative values for vertial bias so.. I added guide line to take the same height as toolbar and moved it to bottom with additional 35% -> so total height with both views equals 70%. Now, we can constraint our imageView to toolbar top line and guide bottom line. This way our imageView is centered. It works even on landscape mode.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the issue that you are having is that the dimension ratio is not taking effect because the height of the image view is `0dp` and you are constraining the top and bottom of the image view to the bottom of the tool bar and forcing the height to be zero. IMHO this should work, but it doesn't, so here is a work-around.

Define a second horizontal guideline at 70% of the height (see `guidelineToolbarHeight2` in the XML below) and constrain your image view between the parent top (effectively the top of the toolbar) and this new guideline. This will position your image correct over the bottom of the toolbar. I think everything else is OK.

*[A second alternative that I like less is to set the height of the image view to something large like `100000dp`. It just needs to be larger than what you expect the width to be.]*

[image]

[image]

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineToolbarHeight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".35" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineToolbarHeight2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".70" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guidelineToolbarHeight"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineImageStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".33" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineImageEnd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".66" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/avatar_diver"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guidelineToolbarHeight2"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="W,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guidelineImageStart"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guidelineImageEnd"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is a shorter version, but the results are the same:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.35"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/avatar_diver"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.33" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.70" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I used your first code snippet. But it gives me [this output](https://i.imgur.com/CDBZHZG.png)

Comment: @HasanAbdullah Post your new XML that gives that result. Which version of constraint layout are you using?

Comment: Sir, I used [this code](https://pastebin.com/LaPViPKk) and got that output. FYI: in the landscape mode it works fine by this code.

Comment: @HasanAbdullah The PasteBin code you supplied works OK in my designer in portrait and landscape. Which version of constraint layout are you using? Also, what is your image size and type (PNG, etc.)

Comment: @HasanAbdullah I will bet that you are using 1.1.0-beta1 of `ConstraintLayout`. Update to version 1.1.0-beta3 and the layout will start to work for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support multiple screen sizes then I think you have to do that programmatically. I'll discuss the cause later.

My device is Xiaomi Mi A1 and its resolution is 1080:1920. So aspect ratio is 16:9. I'll discuss the solution for this device first.

Our target is to set the center of the `ImageView` aligned with `guidelineToolbarHeight` which is at 35% of the screen height. Now if we can draw another guideline (`guidelineImageTop`) for setting the top of `ImageView` aligned with it then our problem would be solved. Question is, at which percentage of screen height we should draw `guidelineImageTop`.

As our `ImageView`s height is equal to the width, let's start from calculating width.

```
width = 33% of 1080 = 356.4
height = width = 356.4
halfHeight = height/2 = 178.2
```

Our `guidelineImageTop` should be `halfHeight` above the `guidelineToolbarHeight`.

```
guidelineToolbarHeights position in pixel = 35% of 1920 = 672
guidelineImageTops position in pixel = 672 - 178.2 = 493.8
Imagine, x% of 1920 = 493.8
x = 25.7
```

So, our `guidelineImageTop` should be at 25% of the screen height. I have edited your code like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="me.mazid.test.MainActivity">

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guidelineToolbarHeight"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".35" />

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MyApp.ActionBar"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guidelineToolbarHeight"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guidelineImageStart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".33" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guidelineImageEnd"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".66" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guidelineImageTop"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".25" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:src="@drawable/avatar_diver"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,1:1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guidelineImageStart"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guidelineImageEnd"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guidelineImageTop" />
```

**Acknowledgement:**

- This solution will not work if you rotate the device in landscape mode. Because aspect ratio will be changed.
- For supporting multiple devices with different aspect ratio, you may have to calculate the percentage of device height and position the `guidelineImageTop` programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is not currently possible using ConstraintLayout directly. You have to calculate image final destination in Java Code. Follow this code :

`XML :`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineToolbarHeight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".35" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineToolbarHeight2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".35" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guidelineToolbarHeight"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineImageStart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".33" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guidelineImageEnd"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".66" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guidelineToolbarHeight2"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="h,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guidelineImageStart"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guidelineImageEnd" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

`Java Code :`

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.constraint.Guideline;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView iv;
    private int imageHeight, screenHeight;
    private Guideline guideLine;
    private ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        iv = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        guideLine = findViewById(R.id.guidelineToolbarHeight2);
        params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) guideLine.getLayoutParams();

        //Get Display Height
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

        //Get ImageView Current Height
        ViewTreeObserver vto = iv.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                iv.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                imageHeight = iv.getMeasuredHeight();

                //getting screen height where guideline will be placed
                float predictedGuidelinePlacementHeight = ((screenHeight * 35) / 100) - (imageHeight/2); // 35 is your guideline percentage for toolbar

                //change guideline constraint percentage
                params.guidePercent = ((predictedGuidelinePlacementHeight * 100) / screenHeight) / 100;
                guideLine.setLayoutParams(params);

                return true;
            }
        });




    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "1.1.0-beta3" release of ConstraintLayout allows the usage of percentage dimensions and many more cool features.

Just set the "layout_constraintHeight_default" attribute to "percent" (to use percentage units), and set the percentage using "layout_constraintHeight_percent". (width related attributes are available too)

Here's the solution

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".35"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/space"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/space"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/space"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".33" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

As you can see, I had to add a `Space` widget and set its height to `200dp` because for now percentage dimensions collapse when centered to another widget's edge.